# weird symbols when opening a file written in arabic

Tags: unicode, arabic

When I open a TeX file containing arabic letters, I only see weird letters. I tried WinEdt, Emacs, TeXMaker. But when I open the same file using Notepad, it looks OK.  What shoud I do?

Comment: Make sure that the encoding that is used by the editors are inline with the encoding that the one used by Notepad. TeXnicCenter still doesn't support Unicode in a convenient way.

Comment: Instead of the "thank you", which is nice of course, upvote a correct answer and, especially if it solved your problem, accept it please, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an editor that can handle and display Unicode-encoded characters. The ones you mention -- other than notepad -- are probably not Unicode-aware. Actually, the very latest version of [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) *is* Unicode-aware; you may be using a somewhat obsolete version of that program.

Try opening your file with *TeXworks*, *TeXshop* (if you use a Mac), or any other editor that's Unicode-aware, and you should be in business.